# MongoDB - aggregating data between two collections

Tags: mongodb, fullcalendar, aggregation-framework, mean-stack

My application is a reservation system that uses full calendar API. The calendar has a seller and a customer that are routed to view the same calendar and see the same events. The seller creates resources on the calendar and the customer can see the same resources and book them on his end.

My goal: when a customer makes a reservation, I want to check the seller's collection for the ***capacity*** that that current booking contains. If the capacity is **less than or equal** to the number of bookings inside the **resource's booking array**, then the customer cannot further reserve that particular booking.

I have made some research and I am trying to follow this example:
[Mongodb aggregation with 2 collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34410548/mongodb-aggregation-with-2-collections)

Since I have never done aggregation in mongoDB, I am having trouble understanding how to query the data properly.

I have two collections in my MEAN application:

Booking:

```
var bookingSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    userNumber:             { type: Number, required: false },
    resourceNumber:         { type: Number, required: true },
    startDateTime:          { type: Date, required: false, default: Date },
    endDateTime:            { type: Date, required: false, default: Date },
    description:            { type: String, default: false },
    title:                  { type: String, required: true },
    className:              { type: String, required: false},
    bookingIdRef:           { type: String, required: false}
    });
```

Resource:

```
var resourceSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    resourceNumber:         { type: Number, required: true }, //dance studio 1 = resource number
    userNumber:             { type: Number, required: true },
    title:                  { type: String, required: true },
    numberOfBookings:       { type: Number, required: true },
    numberOfBookingExists:  { type: Boolean, default: false},
    description:            { type: String, default: false },
    booking:
        [
            {
                //_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                //each array contains _id which we can use instead of slotId // _id slot
                capacityPerBooking:  { type: Number, required: false},
                startDateTime:       { type: Date, required: false, default: Date },
                endDateTime:         { type: Date, required: false, default: Date },
                className:           { type: String, required: false}
            }
        ]

    });
```

when each resource is created, each booking inside the `booking` array inside resource gets a `capacityPerBooking`. On the customer end, when the customer click on an event on the calendar and clicks **reserve**, it calls a `POST` request, where I perform the aggregation. This is the part where I am a bit confused.

this is the service code:

```
var Booking = require('./booking.db.schema.js');
var Resource = require('../resource/resource.db.schema');

module.exports = class BookingService {

    //========================================================
    // create
    //========================================================
    create(req, res, sourceBooking, callback) {
        console.log('+ bookingService.create(%s)', JSON.stringify(sourceBooking));

        //create a resource
        var targetBooking = new Booking({
                userNumber:             req.user.userNumber,    //Samples always belong to the user who created them
                resourceNumber:         sourceBooking.resourceNumber,
                startDateTime:          sourceBooking.startDateTime,
                endDateTime:            sourceBooking.endDateTime,
                title:                  sourceBooking.title,
                description:            sourceBooking.description,
                className:              sourceBooking.className,
                bookingIdRef:           sourceBooking._id
            });

        var pipeline = [
            {
                "$match": { "resourceNumber" : sourceBooking.resourceNumber},
                //"$group": { _id: null, capacityPerBooking: { $lte: sourceBooking.capacityPerBooking } }
            }
        ];

        console.log('pipeline: ' + JSON.stringify(pipeline, null, 2));

        Booking.aggregate(pipeline, function(err, results) {
            if (err)
            {
                throw err, console.log('aggregation error: ' + err);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(results, undefined, 4));
            }

        });

        Booking.find({"resourceNumber" : sourceBooking.resourceNumber}).lean().exec(function (err, objs){
            var ids = objs.map(function (o) { return o.coll_id; }),
                pipeline = [
                    {
                        "$match": { "_id" : { "$in": ids },
                            "capacityPerBooking": { "$lte": "capacityPerBooking" } }
                    },
                    {
                        "$group": {
                            "_id": null,

                        }
                    }
                ];

            console.log('pipeline: ' + JSON.stringify(pipeline, null, 2));
            Resource.aggregate(pipeline, function(err, results) {
                    if (err)
                    {
                        throw console.log('++aggregation error++ : ' + err);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(results, undefined, 4));
                    }

                });
        });
        var tempArray = [];
        Booking.aggregate([
            { "$lookup": {
                "from": "Resource",
                "localField": "resourceNumber",
                "foreignField": "resourceNumber",
                "as": tempArray
            }},
            { "$match": { "Resource.0": { "$resourceNumber": sourceBooking.resourceNumber } } }
        ])

        console.log('tempArray: ' + JSON.stringify(tempArray, null, 2));


        targetBooking.save(function(err, newBooking) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                callback(err, null);
            } else {
                callback(null, newBooking);
            }
        });
}
```

Note: `soureBooking` contains data about the booking to be reserved which was passed via `POST`.

I know my steps have to be as follows:

  1. look at `resource` collection for the `capacityPerBooking`

  2. match the `resourceNumber` from `Booking` to `Resource.booking[]`

  3. compare the number of bookings with that **resourceNumber** against the `capacity`

  4. create booking if $lte, otherwise, throw error

My question is, how do I go about setting something like this up. I have never done aggregation in mongoDB, and having some trouble following the docs on their website. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated!